# Stop audio when is playing another one in Unity2D

Tags: c#

How can I make the first stop playing when playing the second music?
I'm making a selection of music and I want the player to be able to choose what to listen to
But if the player turns on the second music, then it will overlap with the first and 2 tracks will play

```
public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour
{
public Sprite audioOn;
public Sprite audioOff;
public GameObject buttonAudio;

public Slider slider;

public AudioClip clip;
public AudioSource audio;

void Update()
{
    audio.volume = slider.value;
    
}
public void OnOffAudio()
{
    if (AudioListener.volume == 1)
    {
        AudioListener.volume = 0;
        buttonAudio.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = audioOff;
    }
    else
    {
        AudioListener.volume = 1;
        buttonAudio.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = audioOn;
    }
}
 public void PlaySound()
{
 audio.Play();
}
}
```